# I have an event handler registered to "document" element, how do I trigger this handler from another project?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Our company's code base infrastructure has 3 WEB Projects (components containing js, html and css) which we inject into "Project 1" that build up the look of the website.

Now in "Project 1" I have a couple of jQuery animations that are triggered on click event.

In "Project 2" I have a button that should trigger those animations, but I don't want to copy and paste the code to perform those animations, instead, I want to send an event trigger and in "Project 1" handle that event, how do I do that across projects?

I have tried in "Project 1" binding custom event like so

```
$(document).on("searchEvent", () => {
    // Also perform the animations when "searchEvent" is triggered in Project 2
});
```

Then in "Project 2", I'm triggering this event like so

```
$(".secondarySearchButotn").click(() => {
    $(document).trigger("searchEvent");
})
```

The result is that nothing happens when that button is clicked.

I'd like to be able to use the existing code from "Project 1" that manages the animations and use the code to execute the event handler which is triggered in "Project 2".

Comment: I dont think that will be a good idea. This will cause tight coupling between the different projects. Better you make a library file and use it

Comment: `document` variable refers to the *current* document...

Comment: How are you injecting the components into the final website? As iframes perchance?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Is there more than ```1``` current Document?

Comment: @HoriaComan nope, we use JSONP to make cross-domain requests, where we download the HTML contents and simply inject it at a specific position in the DOM.

Comment: @brk If this was possible, I think there would be no coupling at all? Because of the event listeners would listen for a particular event rather than a particular element?